# express-validator with TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, express-validator

I have tried to convert my NodeJS with ExpressJS to TypeScript.

I got a problem with 'express-validator' middleware.

I installed the definition with typings:

```
typings install dt~express-validator --global --save
```

I expect the `req: express.Request` to have express-validator's definitions (i.e. req.checkQuery, req.checkParams, and so on).

But when compiled I got ...

```
error TS2339: Property 'checkQuery' does not exist on type 'Request'.
```

Do I have to import something to make it work ?

Thank you.

Following is my code ..

```
import * as express from 'express';

let router: express.Router = express.Router();

router.get('/somepath', function (req: express.Request, res, next) {
  // code

  req.checkQuery('getparam', 'Invalid getparam').isInt(); // error

  // code
});

export = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is a little old, I'll assume that at the time of writing, the DefinitelyTyped typings were outdated.
This is not uncommon at all, as their typings must be written by the community.

Starting with [v3.1.0](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator/releases/tag/v3.1.0)+, the typings are built into the express-validator, therefore you don't need to include them via DefinitelyTyped anymore.